# Why does TypeScript want another undefined check within a callback?

Tags: typescript

Sometimes I stumble across this:

```
if (obj.needle) { // obj = { needle?: string }
  console.log(obj.needle) // no error here

  matches((haystack) => {
    return haystack.needle === obj.needle // Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
  })
}
```

It seems like TypeScript needs another check within the callback function.
I'd like to know a) *why?* and b) *how to fix this elegantly - without another check*, because it's **not** an async function and there's no way that `obj.needle` is suddenly `'undefined'`.

Comment: The compiler has no way to know for sure if the variable will be undefined **at the time of invoking the callback**. While it's certainly not undefined when calling `matches`, it in turns provides no certainty of when it'll be invoked (at least from the compiler perspective).

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about `obj` and not `haystack`? When I try out your code I don't have the typescript error. Try [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVgLggbwgOxCAJqA-EgZzACcBLNAcwgF8IBeFagKCYDMBXNAYzFKjQgBbAIZguACxAEAFMITSYCYWgCeASjoA+AG5RSWNcmZNSrCNNhwAdBmyg1KCAHon0ePUe2cIfBCJlKGiYICC5+AihQK2AoCgt4G0xvBxd0KAgQYmIoYghJYhAWEJExSRlpcWEVImEuAGsHLRRgkIgCsHZiAUrqsFq6xLsQejoGS0HvZ1cAUSycpAB5eBAeCFICCAAHKAICUhhgFQgAck4sEFZybGOrFuo1JmogA).

Comment: @Alejandro but `matches` (I mean the callback) is called **immediately**, just *right after* the `console.log()`, what magic does TypeScript think happens in between?

Comment: TS doesn't know that `matches` only invokes this callback while `obj` is defined. As far as TS knows, `matches` could hang on to the function and call it at some random time later when `obj` could be anything. Or `matches` could also itself change `obj` before invoking the callback. There are a lot of things TS doesn't know.

Comment: @kraftwer1 You know that because you know the exact implementation of `matches`, but the compiler has no idea of this fact, it may call it right now, or it may call it much latter, or even never at all. It's precisely the *lack* of magic what triggers this error. While you know for sure that the error will never happen because of the shape of your code, the compiler isn't smart enough to realize. Like in every other language, the developer is usually much better informed than the compiler to know certain facts.

Comment: But is there no way I could tell Typescript this callback should be handled as if called directly and that it doesn't mutate state? It is irritating to have nice helpers like `withoutUndoRecording` and then have to do new null-checks inside all of these callbacks that are supposed to help write leaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript doesn't know that `matches` only invokes this callback while `obj` is defined. As far as TS knows, `matches` could hang on to the function and call it at some random time later when `obj` could be anything. Or `matches` could also itself change `obj` before invoking the callback. There are a lot of ways `obj` could change before this callback is invoked as far as TS knows.

There are a few possible solutions. A one line fix is just to create a const copy of the object that TS knows can't change:

```
if (obj.needle) { // obj = { needle?: string }
  console.log(obj.needle) // no error here

  const constObj = obj
  matches((haystack) => {
    return haystack.needle === constObj.needle
  })
}
```

Another option is to create a function which generates the callback (essentially the same thing but with a little more code):

```
const createMatcher = obj => haystack => {
    return haystack.needle === obj
}

if (obj?.needle) { // obj = { needle?: string }
  console.log(obj.needle) // no error here

  matches(createMatcher(obj))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke toLowerCase to actually get the error you're talking about:

this is how it happens:

```
const obj: {needle?: string} = {needle: "hello"};

if (obj.needle) { // obj = { needle?: string }
    console.log(obj.needle) // no error here

    matches((haystack) => {
        // Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        return obj.needle.toLowerCase() === haystack.needle.toLowerCase() 
    })
}

function matches(func: (haystack: {needle: string}) => boolean) {
    obj.needle = undefined;
    func({ needle: "whatever" });
}
```